# jquery mobile back button click event

Tags: jquery, button, mobile, click, back

I have already a project in the appstore. Unfortunately I discovered a strange click event on my back button.

But luckily I have a possibility to handle click events afterwards as I am afterloading some javascript dynamically. The button has no extra class or something else and there are more back buttons on my page.

Now my question, how can I handle my click event such as:

```
$('data-rel[back]').live('click', function()
{
//not fired...
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: post code for `data-rel[back]` elements.

Comment: I have a back button:

<a href="" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Zur&uuml;ck</a>

And I want to know how to check if it is clicked or not. I can not modify the link, I just can afterload some javascript!

Comment: $('a[data-rel="back"]').live('click', function() ... is the right way